# Can a Duskblade channel Magic Weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, class-feature

Can a duskblade use his Arcane Channeling ability to channel the spell *magic weapon*? I haven't found this dealt with anywhere.

Comment: Could you explain why this would be a thing? (My limited imagination prevents me from thinking of a situation wherein a duskblade would *want* to channel the spell *magic weapon*.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan To put the spell on all of your allies' weapons with a single casting, presumably. (Using the 13th level Arcane Channeling, I mean.)

Comment: @Miniman I guess, but unless the duskblade's deliberately using an appropriate weapon (e.g. a sap) [he'll risk breaking his friends' weapons](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/38117/8610) as he's forced to hit them in melee combat. But, yeah, that might be a thing. I'd still like the querent to chime in, though.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yeah, I wasn't suggesting it as a good idea - just the only reason I could think of to do this. (All else aside, at 13th level no one should be carrying a weapon that could be affected by *magic weapon* .)

Answer (score 4):

### Arcane Channeling can channel any spell that has a range of touch.

The first weapon you touch during your attack action on the round which you channel Magic Weapon gains an enhancement bonus to that weapon. If you resolve Arcane Channeling with Shocking Grasp, you deliver that spell upon hitting the target specified in the spell.

The target of Magic weapon is a weapon touched, the target of Shocking grasp is a creature touched.